# using postgres with nodejs for connection pool

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

i am using nodejs as my REST api host. The overall functionality is pretty basic. that is, make a REST call which should do a postgres db query and return data. The problem I am having is the overall code organization.

I have the server.js which has basic initialization. Now, where should i place the postgres connection and call it to query db whenever i need it. current structure is as below. so i think i should be moving the postgres connect code to server.js? what should be the right structure

**server.js**

```
"use strict";

 var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 4001,
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
var routes = require('./api/routes/pushRoutes');
routes(app);

app.listen(port);
console.log('push notification server started on: ' + port);
```

**pushController.js**

```
'use strict';

exports.send_notification = function(req, res) {
    console.log("start of send_notification ");

     if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var jsonString = '';

        req.on('data', function (data) {
            jsonString += data;
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));
            var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
            var timeNow = json.message;

            //get device token from db
            var deviceToken = '';
            var pg = require('pg')
            var format = require('pg-format')
            var PGUSER = 'deploy'
            var PGDATABASE = 'oscpushserver'
            var config = {
              user: PGUSER, // name of the user account
              database: PGDATABASE, // name of the database
              max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
              idleTimeoutMillis: 30000 
            }

            var pool = new pg.Pool(config)
            var myClient

            pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
              if (err) console.log(err)
              app.listen(3000, function () {
                console.log('listening on 3000')
              })
              myClient = client
              var ageQuery = format('SELECT * from push_table WHERE seq_id = 1')
              myClient.query(ageQuery, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err)
                }
                console.log("row data:" + result.rows[0])
                console.log("device id from db:" + result.rows[0].device_id)
                deviceToken =result.rows[0].device_id;


              })
            });


            res.json(JSON.parse(jsonString));
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: Looks about right, if you want to have shorter code, you might want to try https://node-postgres.com/

Comment: well the app inside pool.connect is not resolved in my case as it is defined in the server.js

Comment: Oh wait my bad you are already using node-postgres. May I ask why do you put app inside pool. You already have the app listening on server.js

Comment: well i copy pasted code from 2 different locations and i m super new to nodejs. so didnt know how to resolve it

Comment: [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo) offers the best code structure for the database that you can find for use with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you want to make a REST api that just gets data from db.

**server.js**

Looks fine in most parts, except that you are not using the routes correctly. To use the routes you have defined you use app.use:

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

**database.js**
I would create another file where you can put the database credentials in one place and create a new pool.

```
var pg = require('pg')
var PGUSER = 'deploy'
var PGDATABASE = 'oscpushserver'
var config = {
  user: PGUSER, // name of the user account
  database: PGDATABASE, // name of the database
  max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000 
}

var pool = new pg.Pool(config);

module.exports = pool;
```

**pushController**

I assume that you want to require this file in server.js. So make sure that the path points to '.../pushController' and not './api/routes/pushRoutes'.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const format = require('pg-format');
const pool = require('../path/to/database.js');

router.get(function(req, res, next) {
  pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    var ageQuery = format('SELECT * from push_table WHERE seq_id = 1')
    client.query(ageQuery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw new Error(err);
      res.json(result.rows[0]); 
    })
  }); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

So now, a GET request to your API server should return a json object from your postgres database.

There are loads of examples online on how to make REST APIs with node and postgres. One of them is this: https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-todo.

Comment: how would i share the pool across multiple route files in my router? I have a separate file for each endpoint in ./routes directory and need to instantiate the pool in one spot in the app and expose it to all the routes. In koa I can stick the connection pool instance on `ctx.pool`, is it possible with express?